# In JavaScript how would I show only one element at a time

Tags: javascript, dom

I have created this simple JavaScript code that allows a user to click on elements and then show the user what's hidden.

However right now my code allows the user to click on all the of elements and reveal them all at the same time.

I was wondering if anyone could push me in the right direction?

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MTJa5/

```
var hellos = function(){
    var divClicks = document.getElementsByClassName("clickToShow");
    for(i=0; i < divClicks.length; i++){
        var click = divClicks[i];

        var close = function(){
            var open = false;

            click.addEventListener("click", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
                if(open){
                    this.childNodes[3].setAttribute("class", "hidden");
                    open = false;
                } else {
                    this.childNodes[3].setAttribute("class", "show");
                    open = true;
                }
            },false);
        }();
    }
}();
```

Comment: When I click on the `div`s in your demo, only one hidden element is toggled.  Isn't that the behavior you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah but you can click and open two. I want it so that if you have one open and click on another the first one closes.

Comment: No. I am interested in learning JavaScript soley and then moving on to jQuery for cross browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: http://jsfiddle.net/MTJa5/22/

Answer (score 0):

When you show any one element you need to go through the other divs and hide their elements.

EDIT: see this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/spb_/MTJa5/25/

Comment: I forgot you were in a click handler so `i` is going to be the wrong thing to check for.  I updated the code, can you try again?

Comment: When you click down them all and then click on the first or second it takes two clicks to get it open.

Comment: Also could you make your variables more understandable?

Comment: yes that is correct.  It's happening because `open` is tracked per div.  I'm not sure how to update the other `open`'s so you could change `if(open)` to `if(this.childNodes[3].getAttribute("class") == "show")`, but this is not as efficient.

Answer (score 0):

hi buddy gone through your fiddle work and found the below solution..

This is a complete javascript in your fiddle with modification::

```
var hellos = function(){
    var divClicks = document.getElementsByClassName("clickToShow");
    for(i=0; i < divClicks.length; i++){
        var click = divClicks[i];


        var close = function(){
            var open = false;
            click.addEventListener("click", function(e){
                var divVisible= document.getElementsByClassName("show");
        //alert(divVisible.length);
        for(j=0; j < divVisible.length; j++){
            divVisible[j].setAttribute("class", "hidden");
        }

            e.preventDefault();
                if (open){
               this.childNodes[3].setAttribute("class", "hidden");
                    open = false;
                }else{
                    this.childNodes[3].setAttribute("class", "show");
                    open = true;
                }

            },false);
        }();
    }
}();
```

Here is the explaination::

on your click event i have found all the div elements with `class=show` and in a

`for loop` i have set `class=hidden` again then rest your code handles the stuff, of displaying the respective div on click